# url-pattern in tomcat and jetty

Tags: tomcat, jetty, servlet-filters

In my java web app I've got the following url-pattern for a filter:

```
<url-pattern>*-template</url-pattern>
```

It works fine in jetty 9 but tomcat 8 rejects it saying it's invalid. How come? Also, I cannot make tomcat understand an url-pattern like `/*/*-template` (If I specify the exact url `/foo/bar-template`, only then tomcat uses my filter. But I don't want to specify every single url. What are my options?

Answer (score 0):

Probably because Tomcat is implementing the spec more strictly. From the Java Servlet Specification 3.1 (section 12.2):

> In the Web application deployment descriptor, the following syntax is
>   used to define mappings:
>
> - A string beginning with a ‘/’ character and ending with a ‘/*’ suffix is used for path mapping.
> - A string beginning with a ‘*.’ prefix is used as an extension mapping.
> - The empty string ("") is a special URL pattern that exactly maps to the application's context root, i.e., requests of the form
>     `http://host:port/<contextroot>/`. In this case the path info is ’/’
>     and the servlet path and context path is empty string (““).
> - A string containing only the ’/’ character indicates the "default" servlet of the application. In this case the servlet path is the
>     request URI minus the context path and the path info is null.
> - All other strings are used for exact matches only.